# Streamlit time input function doesn't support each single time

Tags: python, python-3.x, streamlit

[image]

Is there any way to show the time menu like above on streamlit? This menu should show every single hour and minute. Other hand streamlit time input provides only pre defined time arrivals like 08:00 08:15 08:30 08:45 etc. I don't want this. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Go to streamlit github and make a feature request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  start = "00:00"
    end = "23:59"
    times = []
    start = now = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, "%H:%M")
    end = datetime.datetime.strptime(end, "%H:%M")
    while now != end:
        times.append(str(now.strftime("%H:%M")))
        now += datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
    times.append(end.strftime("%H:%M"))
    st.multiselect('Departure hour:',times)
```

Answer (score 0):

Improved answer:

```py
times = []
for hours in range(0, 23):
  for minutes in range(0, 59):
    times.append(datetime.time(hours, minutes))
st.selectbox("Time", times, key="time", format_func=lambda t: t.strftime("%H:%M"))
```